# How can I find the point (X, Y, Z) which minimizes this quantity?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, algorithms

I have a number of equally powerful light sources $L_i, 1 \le i \le N$ at points within a cube $(x_i, y_i, z_i), -1 \le x_i, y_i, z_i \le 1$. The intensity of each light falls off with distance according to an inverse-square law, as usual. This means that at $(x, y, z)$ the total intensity is given by:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^N \frac{1}{(x - x_i)^2 + (y - y_i)^2 + (z - z_i)^2}$$

What method/algorithm can I use to find the point within the cube $(X, Y, Z), -1 \le X, Y, Z \le 1$ where this quantity is minimal?

How would this method change if I wanted to restrict $(X, Y, Z)$ (but not $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$) to be within a (convex) sub-volume of the cube, e.g. the cylinder $X^2 + Y^2 \le 0.75^2, -0.25 <= Z <= 0.75$?

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty of your problem is due to the fact that you have quadratic forms under the fraction bars. In my opinion, there is no quick and easy way to solve this optimization problem as it is non-convex. However, grid-search is not a bad choice here, as you have only three variables. In the latter search prcedure you just try all points inside the cube within a certain grid density. The latter search can also be easily generalized to arbitray search domains (balls, cyliners).